# Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonatype.mavenbook.App Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.mavenbook.App

Tags: java, maven, jar, classnotfoundexception

I am currently reading [maven the definitve guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517335), and the very first project installed via archetype, I tried to `mvn install`. Then the following `jar` file `simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, when run as `java -cp target/simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.sonatype.mavenbook.App`, I got:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonatype.mavenbook.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.mavenbook.App
```

How can I solve this?

The layout created as:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03 -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook
```

The final layout (output from previous command):

```
.
└── simple
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   └── java
        │       └── org
        │           └── sonatype
        │               └── mavenbook
        │                   └── ch03
        │                       └── App.java
        └── test
            └── java
                └── org
                    └── sonatype
                        └── mavenbook
                            └── ch03
                                └── AppTest.java
```

`jar` file generated as `mvn install` in root directory (where the .pom file is). Then the modified layout (with addition of the `target` directory looks like this:

```
.
└── simple
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   └── java
    │   │       └── org
    │   │           └── sonatype
    │   │               └── mavenbook
    │   │                   └── ch03
    │   │                       └── App.java
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── org
    │               └── sonatype
    │                   └── mavenbook
    │                       └── ch03
    │                           └── AppTest.java
    └── target
        ├── classes
        │   └── org
        │       └── sonatype
        │           └── mavenbook
        │               └── ch03
        │                   └── App.class
        ├── generated-sources
        │   └── annotations
        ├── generated-test-sources
        │   └── test-annotations
        ├── maven-archiver
        │   └── pom.properties
        ├── maven-status
        │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
        │       ├── compile
        │       │   └── default-compile
        │       │       ├── createdFiles.lst
        │       │       └── inputFiles.lst
        │       └── testCompile
        │           └── default-testCompile
        │               ├── createdFiles.lst
        │               └── inputFiles.lst
        ├── simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ├── surefire-reports
        │   ├── org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03.AppTest.txt
        │   └── TEST-org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03.AppTest.xml
        └── test-classes
            └── org
                └── sonatype
                    └── mavenbook
                        └── ch03
                            └── AppTest.class
```

now if I try to run the packaged jar file from the root directory:

```
java -cp target/simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.sonatype.mavenbook.App
```

I got:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonatype.mavenbook.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.mavenbook.App
```

Comment: You should tell us more. Show us the project structure (the directories), show us the class in question, show us how you compiiler it, and also show us from which directory you are calling what exact command.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose see edits

Comment: Do you see that the directory of the file `App.java` (and of the corresponding file `App.class`) is `org/sonatype/mavenbook/ch03` and not only `org/sonatype/mavenbook`? So the fully qualified class name is most propbably `org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03.App`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you are right, the fully qualified name is with the `ch03` package name